# qmake syntax and redirecting stdout from sed to other sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, qmake, text-processing

I have qmake project with target which generates documentation. Away of qmake in pure bash I would write like this:

```
PWDMOD=$(echo $PWD | sed -e 's/\//\\\//g') ;
sed -i 's/INPUT = /INPUT = $PWDMOD\/src\/fileset/g' $PWD/Doxyfile
```

Yep, I need to correct to INPUT variable in Doxyfile while `make doc` executed. But in my case - in qmake environment, I wrote this:

```
doc.commands = \
(PWDMOD=$(echo $$PWD | sed -e 's/\//\\\//g') ; \
sed -i 's/INPUT = /INPUT = $$PWDMOD\/src\/fileset/g' $$PWD/Doxyfile ; \
...
```

and qmake parser sent me error message about first line. Something like "Incorrect using parenthesses in way like this $(...)".

So how I should write such qmake code? Or how can I redirect stdout from first sed command to second to avoid such situation? Thanks.

Comment: Not familiar with qmake, but generally would expect a double dollar sign to be necessary. But the whole problem is overengineered; just use a different separator in `sed`. Something like `doc.commands = sed -i "s%INPUT = %INPUT = $$PWD/src/fileset/%g" $$PWD/Doxyfile`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint @tripleee about "%". It makes qmake code looks clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice `~=` function in `qmake` that will save you one extra call to `sed`.

```
PWDMOD = $$PWD
PWDMOD ~= s,/,\\/,g
doc.commands = sed -i \'s/INPUT = /INPUT = $$PWDMOD\\/src\\/fileset/g\' $$PWD/Doxyfile
```

Comment: Thanks, @svlasov, I will keep in mind about ~= operator. But in this situation using operator that works with regex over sed it seems too complicated.